# paypal integration in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal gateway in my aspx page having shopping cart. I succeed to commit transaction using express checkout method generated by paypal integration wizard but what I am being unable to do is sending product quantity and details to paypal page.

And how can I redirect to my own review page where shipping and billing address is present after log in into the paypal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can i redirect to my own review page where shipping and billing address

First you need to send a unique number id for the order that is connected to your database with the information that you like to show after the purchase.

Then you send the "return" parametre with the full url with the unique id of your order that your customer will return and you need to show the final informations.

eg:
`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.urls.con/orderinfos.aspx?TID=112999182">`

of cource for better protection is good to encode some how your order id. All of that exist on the paypal sdk manual.

Also return url are the `"notify_url"` to be notify even if the user not return, and `"cancel_return`" in case of cancel the payment

You can also search for [PDT for the return](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer), and [IPN for the notify](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) for more advanced information.